# Plugin from WordPress.com for comment notification...available?

Tags: comments, plugins, notifications

WordPress.com has a rather cool feature when you add comments. The two features are:

```
   [x] Notify me of follow-up comments via email.
   [x] Notify me of new posts via email.
```

Is this plugin available somewhere so that I can include it on my privately hosted blog?

Comment: Possibly Jetpack but recommendations are off topic here and not in this stacks scope. Try the software recommendations stack instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gurken-subscribe-to-comments/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/subscribe2/