# How to migrate from Mark Jaquith's Subscribe to Comments plugin to Gurken's new version?

Tags: plugins, updates, migration

Mark Jaquith's [Subscribe to Comments plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/subscribe-to-comments/) has been a staple of my WordPress site since shortly after I launched it. However, it's not really maintained any more (last updated end of 2007) and it lacks some options (email verification, etc.).

[infogurke](http://profiles.wordpress.org/users/infogurke/) extended Mark's plugin and released [a different version](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gurken-subscribe-to-comments/) with enhancements:

> - All of the original Subscribe to Comments
> - Registration with Double-Opt-In
> - Multi-Language (English and German included)
> - You can define an own css file for the manager interface
> - Fixed many bugs that are still in the original plugin

Is it possible to migrate to infogurke's version and maintain the subscriptions in the database?

(Found the new plugin via [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2409/plugin-from-wordpress-com-for-comment-notification-available).)

Comment: According to Mark updated version of his plugin is in development and will be released. Unfortunately no estimates on when so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible (and quite easy) to migrate from Mark Jaquith's Subscribe to Comments plugin to Gurken Subscribe to Comments plugin.

The steps:

1. Install Gurken Subscribe to Comments (using either FTP or WordPress's plugin manager)
2. Don't activate Gurken StC yet. First deactivate Mark Jaquith's version.

   - Activating the new plugin too soon will fail because both plugins define functions with the same names.
3. Activate Gurken StC.
4. Go in via FTP and delete the `/wp-content/plugins/subscribe-to-comments/` folder.

   - **Don't use WordPress to delete Mark's version!** It might erase your subscription data from the database!

(Question and answer inspired by [this WordPress Support thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-gurken-subscribe-to-comments-migrate-from-mark-jaquiths-plugin).)

Comment: Do you get points for answering your own question, when the question and answer both come from somewhere else?

Comment: I would think that as long as the answer is good, why not. The point of the site is good questions with good answers, I personally do not care where they come from providing attribution is given when required.

Comment: I figured it'd be OK, since I asked the question over there and also figured out the actual process. (The plugin's author just said, basically, try it, it should work, but don't blame "me" if something breaks.) I did gain rep for the question and the answer, but other users voted them up; it's impossible to vote for your own contributions (as it should be).